# How can I have list of all users logged in and choose kill your cookie/session in Express/NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, express

how can i have a list of all users logged in my webapp ?

I have a login and need know how many people are logged, and if I want kill a cookie/session from their... What is the best way?

Kind Regards

Comment: which session store are you using?

Comment: express-session

Answer (score 0):

i ll try to give you an example as simple as possible.

-> create a session table in your db

-> when the user logs in generate a new session entry it can be as simple as an object with (token, username). (for simplicity reasons i ll assume that sessions last forever until the user logs himself out)

-> now you are able to count how many entries you have in that table, this will give you the desired information of how many people are logged in.

-> now for the second part, you can request the user to send you the token with every request he makes, and you match the token against the db and verify if it checks.

-> when you want to kill a session just go into your table and delete that specific entry you are looking for, the next time the user makes a request his token will no longer be in the db and you can say "he is no longer logged in" , the same applies when the user log himself out.